# list of files with space in the name

Tags: r, parsing, pattern-matching

I would like to get the list of files with a specific extention in a folder. However, these files has space in the name. So for example, imagining I have files named `file test1.txt, file test2.txt, file test3.txt, file test4.txt`, if I do

```
list.files(pattern="file test*.txt")
```

I got

```
character(0)
```

NOTA: Apparentely, using simply `pattern="file test*"` it works fine but I need the extention file as well.

Comment: Can't you add `.txt` after the wildcard character in your note at the end?

Comment: Or try `list.files(pattern="file test.*.txt")`

Comment: The issue is I have same name for all files with different extentions `.txt` and `.csv` or `.xls` and I want just `.txt`.

Comment: @ACE and Laterow - both of those solutions work; you should add them as answers.

Comment: @Laterow: It seems to work! thanks! but I never thought of that as it has no sense... :)

Comment: No problem! that's what we're here for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
list.files(pattern="file test.*.txt")
```

Actually, what this says is:

```
list.files(pattern="file test(.*).txt")
```

(which also works). `.` refers to any character and `*` refers to the idea that this character should be present 0 or more times (see `?regex`).

Comment: I guess the issue was the space in the name as the pattern should work also without the `.`. maybe in this way, it parses fine for some strange reason

Comment: To me more specific `"file test(.*)\\.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

In your kast example you said that using `pattern="file test*"` works but you need a way to search for the extension as well.

All you have to do is Change your code to `pattern="file test.*.txt"`. This would make your code search for any filename that matched "file testX.txt" with any one character in place of X.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do.  `pattern="file test*.txt"`

Comment: no problem! I was just worried it was a terrible silly question!